# Microsoft Power BI - Publish to Web, what's the per user license catch?

Tags: powerbi

I recently installed Microsoft Power BI. To cut things short, I manage to generate some dummy data and used the 'Publish to Web' tool to get an  link and embed the report on the web.

After doing so, it seems EVERYONE is able to access the report/dashboard.
This is despite Microsoft has a per user licensing policy listed under [https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/](http://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/)

It clearly says that it's a per user viewer license. This is further echoed in it's forums:
https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Service/new-power-bi-licensing/td-p/169154

So what's the catch? How come I am able to publish my web reports and let everyone see it for free? I am currently on the PRO License.

Just need to make this clear before our company starts choosing MS Power BI as our BI platform of choice.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that 'Publish To Web' does enable NON Licence holders to access the data - the reason there is no cost associated with this (presumably) is because there are a lot of limitations on what type of reports can be published to web AND there is no security for that report, so literally anyone on the planet can view it.

If you are creating sensitive business reports, you won't want to use Publish to Web, even though it's free - as you'd never get your company to agree to publishing your company data online for the world to see

The options with costs associated are embedding those reports in your own Apps / your own intranet etc. - which does require you to have paid for Premium capacity

Or you can have everyone in your organisation have a Pro licence and they can access via the PBI site / PBI Desktop

Which of these options you pick will likely depend on how many people you have in your organisation.  A licence is around £7 a month.

So if you have a small number of users, giving everyone a licence is clearly the most cost efficient way to deliver Power BI.  If you have a lot of users, there's a point where just putting a workspace in Premium Capacity and paying for that, would become more cost effective than giving everyone a licence.

Restrictions on Publish to Web - these things are not allowed:

- Reports with row level security.
- Reports using any Live Connection data source
- Reports shared to you directly or through an organizational content pack.
- Reports in a group in which you are not an edit member.
- "R" Visuals are not currently supported in Publish to web reports.
- Exporting Data from visuals in a report which has been published to the web
- ArcGIS Maps for Power BI visuals